# Model.first does not retrieve first record from table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Model.first doesnot retrive first record from table. Instead it retrives any random record from table.

```
eg:
   Merchant.first
    Query
    SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" LIMIT 1
   => <Merchant id: 6, merchant_name: "Bestylish", description: "", description_html: "" >


Instead the query should be
  SELECT "merchants".* FROM "merchants" ORDER BY "merchants"."id" ASC LIMIT 1;


Why it doesnot retrive the first record
```

Answer (score 3):

Model.first will use the default sorting of your database.
For example. In Postgresql default sorting is not necessarily an id.

Comment: In fact in PostgreSQL there is no default sorting at all, thank gods. The whole thing is very activerecord version-dependent anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be default behaviour with Postgres, as some active-record versions do not add a default ordering to the query for first, while adding one for last.

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9885

PostgreSQL does not by default apply a sort, which is generally a good thing for performance.

So in this context "first" means "the first row returned", not "the first row when ordered by some meaningless key value".

Curiously "last" does seem to order by id.

Comment: Model.last  It orders by id desc in rails.

Comment: Now in Rails 4. This issue is also solved.  Model.first will be order by id asc.

Comment: Yes -- but the behaviour of first is dependent on the RDBMS. It's curious because it's inconsistent. If Rails is so keen on last meaning "the one with the highest primary key value" then it could also specify a behaviour for "first" instead of leaving it to the database.

Comment: It is defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2443e0d11c0db352ec1a7c62748f19042c2c725d/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L368-L374), in Rails, to order by primary key if no other order conditions are specified.

Comment: @MikeCampbell But not in 3.2, for some reason https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb The treatment of order seems to be quite variable.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Indeed, you're right. Judging by the issues on github you highlighted it seems to be something that they took a decision on and chose to explicitly order by primary key in Rails 4.

Comment: @MikeCampbell ... and I'd really object to that if they hadn't kindly put in the take method, so you can get away from all that awful default ordering.

Comment: @DavidAldridge ahh-ha, I didn't know about `take`. Well that seems like a decent solution.

Comment: @MikeCampbell it seems to be to be a better default method than first if just one row is required. I'm not sure that first has any benefit over take in 4.0

Answer (score 1):

It is defined [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2443e0d11c0db352ec1a7c62748f19042c2c725d/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb#L368-L374), in Rails 4, to order by primary key if no other order conditions are specified.

In Rails 3.2.11, it is as such:

```
def find_first
  if loaded?
    @records.first
  else
    @first ||= limit(1).to_a[0]
  end
end
```

Without the `order` method, which will just apply the limit and then leave the ordering up to your database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the ordering yourself. Try calling `Merchant.order('id ASC').first`
It may be possible to automate this using default scopes in your model but I'm not sure about that.